# Rubik Impossible cube with lenticular stickers effect?

Tags: modeling, texturing, node-editor

[image]

I would like to model this, but I don't want to make every sticker of each piece have what this person is trying to make in his tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fE0W5JOTado his way may work, but from past helpful people some of my models had too much topology. This is how the lenticular effect works.

[image]

Is there a way to achieve this effect, maybe without making so many tiny extra faces for 54 stickers. Maybe some collection of nodes that could achieve this effect. I haven't done much with nodes other than to apply textures and that's it. I haven't tried anything yet because I don't know where to start.

UPDATE: I don't know if I'm on the right track, but I'm testing the Fresnel node on a test cube. Maybe that would work if it didn't fade the colors with a circle shape, and instead it swiped across with a straight line from red to blue. Do you have any suggestion to this path, or is there still a better route I should take?

[image]

UPDATE: after applying the nodes in the answer below, this is how the test model looked.

[image]
[image]

Comment: you could also try an Input node > Layer Weight and use its Facing output, maybe it will work better than Fresnel?

Comment: Fresnel together with a colored colorramp

Comment: @moonboots I can always count on your help. When I was typing this question, I was hoping you would see it. Thank you, your idea worked great, and I added an updated GIF to show how it turned out. I'm sure ill come into some extra issues, but I think this was the main one I wanted to solve to really sell the realism look after it's made.

Comment: oh ok good, I was not sure it would work though  ;)

Comment: also just a side question. I'm wondering if maybe i can or should apply some stripped line texture to the principle shader to make these lines you may see for extra realism so when I'm closer to the model the cube looks more real. https://ibb.co/v3j5mBB

Comment: if you want to make these lines you can use a Wave Texture as a mask (in the factor of a Mix Shader in order to separate 2 textures)

Comment: What if I only wanted the colors to be able to shift if the cube is rotated on direction. For example, the stickers all have that lenticular effect in the same direction so if the lines are all verticle then the color only changes if you rotate left and right but if you tilt it up and down then the solved colors won't all show up it still looks scrambled. Is there a way to make that effect happen

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can try this node setup: (as moonboots proposed)

[image]

[image]

Comment: thank you for the visual, that helped a lot. i can always count on moonboots. i added an updated gif

Comment: Also, to add to Chris' answer, you can put a ColorRamp between the Layer Weight and the Mix Shader to see if it helps